# .closest() not finding what it should

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/Kc94u/ - that uses .closest() to see if there's a a div or an input element above where I click:

```
<div>           
            <span>W=</span>
            <input id="Wval" class="ifield" value="123" >
 </div>

$(function(){   // Ready
    $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
        eTarget$ = $('e.target');

        test1 = eTarget$.closest('div').length;
        test2 = eTarget$.closest('input').length;
        debugger;

    })
})
```

But whether I click in the input field or on the W= span element, the length of the found elements always comes back 0.

(I'm running Chrome.  Right-click in results and inspect to open debugger.)

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
  eTarget$ = $('e.target');
```

to this:

```
 eTarget$ = $(e.target); // remove the quotes
```

Comment: Thanks.  So what's the rule? I know it's $(this), but then you also have $('document') and $('body').

Comment: `$(this)` is the current elem which is in the current context, and if you say `$('document')` syntactically its wrong as it holds the quotes inside it, which should not be present in it, so it should be `$(document)`, yes `$('body')` is correct.